# Call API using Refit and deserialize to dynamic

Tags: json, refit

I'm calling a REST service using Refit and I want to deserialize the JSON that is returned as a dynamic type.

I tried defining the interface as

```
[Get("/foo")]
Task<dynamic> GetFoo();
```

but the call times out.

I know I can deserialize to a dynamic like this

```
var mockString = "{ title: { name: 'fred', book: 'job'} }";
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(mockString);
```

but I can't figure out what to pass to Refit to get it to do the same.

Another option would be to get Refit to pass the raw JSON back so I can deserialize it myself but I can't see a way to do that either.

Any ideas?

Comment: why do you need to? what's wrong about a strong type?

Comment: Timeout sounds odd - are you sure that the issue is with the `dynamic` return type? I was able to specify it in a refit interface and got back a `dynamic` (under the hood, a `JObject` - as JSON.NET handles the deserialization) back fine.

Comment: @Thomas I don't know the shape of the JSON ahead of time so can't provide a strong type. If I return a dynamic I can navigate around the data.

Comment: @rdavisau it seems to be something to do with the endpoint I'm using. Other endpoints work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refit uses JSON.NET under the hood, so any deserialization that works with that will work with Refit, **including `dynamic`**. The interface you have described is exactly right.

Here's a real working example:

```
public interface IHttpBinApi
{
    [Get("/ip")]
    Task<dynamic> GetIp();
}

var value = await RestService.For<IHttpBinApi>("http://httpbin.org").GetIp();
```

If you are using iOS and Refit 4+, you might be seeing this bug: https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit/issues/359

As Steven Thewissen has stated, you can use `Task<string>` as your return type (or `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`, or even `Task<HttpContent>`) to receive the raw response and deserialize yourself, but you shouldn't have to -- the whole point of Refit is that it's supposed to save you that hassle.

[UPDATED: 02/2023]

Refit now uses `System.Text.Json` by default (see the comment below), but the approach here should still work.

Comment: Your example works fine. I'm using this endpoint http://mockbin.org/bin/ef5fc5d9-bd0a-4fca-9ce0-ce49ec12b4d6 and it times out when trying return dynamic but works when returning a string.

Comment: Note that as of [v6](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#breaking-changes-in-6x), Refit uses [`System.Text.Json`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview) by default instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can define your interface to return a string and get the raw JSON that way:

```
[Get("/foo")]
Task<string> GetFoo();
```

As described here:
https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit#retrieving-the-response

Comment: I'm trying this but my response is coming through with an extra layer of escaped strings. for example i'm expecting: `{"someField": "value1"}` but i'm getting `"{\r\n  \"someField\": \"value1\"\r\n}"`. Any way around this?